# I am learning shell and need someone who can explain me one thing

Tags: git, shell

I don't want to blindly copypaste so can anybody explain to me what every parameter of this script means ? `find . -exec git check-ignore {} + | xargs -I{} basename {}`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read through the man pages for the commands mentioned there? If after that you're still unsure what's happening, let us know which parts of the docs were unclear and we would be happy to help clarify things.

Comment: Well most confusing is part {} +. I have read mans to both git check-ignore and find but i couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Take a look at the [find man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), and look for the section on `-exec command {} +`.

Comment: Nvm got it all, just ned lil push. Thank You very much <3

Comment: The _xargs_ man page also describes the use of curlies in that command. Basically, the token `{}` does not have a special meaning in the shell, so every command is allowed to understand it in its own way.

Comment: @Piter: If you need help only in how to **use** a certain command (i.e. about the meaning of its arguments), [su] is in general a better place to ask, because Stackoverflow focuses on programming problems.

Comment: @Piter In short (comparing to all the answers in the linked dup) use `git status --ignored` instead.